# Testing the convergency of a sequence.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> **Question.** Let $~f\in C^1[-\pi,\pi]$ be such that $f(-\pi)=f(\pi)$. Define $$a_n=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(t)\cos nt~dt~, ~n\in \mathbb{N}$$
>   Which of the following statements are true?
>
> a. The sequence $\{a_n\}$ is bounded.
>
> b. The sequence $\{na_n\}$ converges to zero as $n \to \infty$
>
> c. The series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^2|a_n|^2$ is convergent.

**My Solution.**

(a) **True**. $|a_n|\le \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|f(t)||\cos nt|dt \le \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|f(t)|dt, ~ \text{for all} ~n \in \mathbb{N}$.

But I can't prove/disprove the other two options. Please help..thank you.

Comment: $f'\in C^0(-\pi,\pi)$ so $f'\in L^2(-\pi,\pi)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For b) and c) you just have to integrate by parts. $a_n=-\frac 1 n \int_{-\pi} ^{\pi} f'(t) \sin (nt) \, dt$ so $na_n$ are the  coefficients of the sine series of  $g=-f'$ which is continuous and periodic. By standard results in the theory of Fourier series b) and c) are both true. In fact $\pi \sum n^{2}|a_n|^{2}\leq\int |f'(t)|^{2} \, dt $

Comment: ...sir can u please refer those results in Fourier series that u are talking...

Comment: Since c. implies b., there is need for only one standard result.

Comment: Almost any book on Fourier series has the result I have used. Examples are Apostol, (baby) Rudin, Fourier series by Edwards etc.

Comment: @uniquesolution Very true. Parseval's identity is the only result needed.

Comment: Thank you so much sir..@KaviRamaMurthy

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy....Sir, for (c) I found a result in Apostol that states: If $~f\in C[0,2\pi]$ and $2\pi$ periodic and $f \sim a_0/2+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(a_n \cos nx +b_n \sin nx)$ Then $$1/\pi \int |f(t)|^2 dt= a_0^2/2+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(a_n^2+b_n^2)$$...But I can't figure out why $b_n=0$ in our problem here...?? Am I missing something..?

Comment: @IndrajitGhosh You are right. I have edited my answer by changing $=$ to $\leq $.